# Looping through objects and creating array then combining on id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a problem trying to build an array, then combine and output multiple objects depending on the id.

This is the problem (I hope it makes sense):

I am looping through multiple objects, then create an array depending on the value of the type of the object. I then take that array and build it into the object. Once that is done I need to run through all the objects and combine any that have the same id.

this is an example of how it would originally look:

```
[{
    "id": "755",
    "entities": ["14394551"],
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "amount": 43,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14394550"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB588328"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "755",
    "entities": ["14394553"],
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "amount": 28,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14394552"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB588333"],
    "exchangerate": 1
},{
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14439896"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 38,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14439895"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2454"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14434400"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 18,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14434399"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2453"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14430895"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 63,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "Dep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14430894"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2452"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "762",
    "entities": ["14350538"],
    "accountID": "762",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST1",
    "amount": 45,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "TEST1",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14350537"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB586991"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "760",
    "entities": ["14350538"],
    "accountID": "760",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST2",
    "amount": 49,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "TEST2",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14321538"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB452756"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}]
```

then this is after the array has been created -> Depending on the type.

```
[
    {
    "id": "755",
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14394551"],
        "amount": 43,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
        "salesOrderId": ["14394550"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB588328"]
    }],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "755",
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14394553"],
        "amount": 28,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
        "salesOrderId": ["14394552"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB588333"],
    }],
    "deposit": []
},{
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14439896"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14439896"],    
        "amount": 38,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
        "salesOrderId": ["14439895"],
        "memo": ["MICGB2454"]
    }],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit" : [{
        "entities": ["14434400"],
        "amount": 18,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
        "salesOrderId": ["14434399"],
        "memo": ["MICGB2453"]
    }],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "Dep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [],
    "deposit": [{
        "entities": ["14430895"],
        "amount": 63,
        "memo": ["MICGB2452"],
    }]
}, {
    "id": "762",
    "accountID": "762",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST1",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [
        {
            "entities": ["14350538"],
            "amount": 45,
            "webPaymentMethod": "TEST1",
            "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
            "salesOrderId": ["14350537"],
            "memo": ["MAINGB586991"],
        }
    ],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "760",
    "accountID": "760",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST2",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14350538"],
        "amount": 49,
        "webPaymentMethod": "TEST2",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
        "salesOrderId": ["14321538"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB452756"]
    }],
    "deposit": []
}]
```

then this would be what I want the final output to be - all the same id objects have the customerDeposit / deposit combined.

```
[
    {
    "id": "755",
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14394551"],
        "amount": 43,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
        "salesOrderId": ["14394550"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB588328"]
    }, {
        "entities": ["14394553"],
        "amount": 28,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
        "salesOrderId": ["14394552"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB588333"],
    }],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14439896"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14439896"],    
        "amount": 38,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
        "salesOrderId": ["14439895"],
        "memo": ["MICGB2454"]
    }, {
        "entities": ["14434400"],
        "amount": 18,
        "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
        "salesOrderId": ["14434399"],
        "memo": ["MICGB2453"]
    }],
    "deposit": [{
        "entities": ["14430895"],
        "amount": 63,
        "memo": ["MICGB2452"],
    }]
}, {
    "id": "762",
    "accountID": "762",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST1",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [
        {
            "entities": ["14350538"],
            "amount": 45,
            "webPaymentMethod": "TEST1",
            "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
            "salesOrderId": ["14350537"],
            "memo": ["MAINGB586991"],
        }
    ],
    "deposit": []
}, {
    "id": "760",
    "accountID": "760",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST2",
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "exchangerate": 1,
    "customerDeposit": [{
        "entities": ["14350538"],
        "amount": 49,
        "webPaymentMethod": "TEST2",
        "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
        "salesOrderId": ["14321538"],
        "memo": ["MAINGB452756"]
    }],
    "deposit": []
}]
```

This is my current code but it is not working as i want as it skips any ids that dont have more than one customerDeposit / deposit as it doesn't get into the `if (objForId)` statement.

```js
function createDeposit(values) {
  deposit = {
    entities: values.entities,
    amount: values.amount,
    memo: values.memo,
  };
  return deposit;
}

function createCustomerDeposit(values) {
  customerDeposit = {
    entities: values.entities,
    amount: values.amount,
    memo: values.memo,
    webPaymentMethod: values.webPaymentMethod,
    webPaymentMethodID: values.webPaymentMethodID,
    salesOrderId: values.salesOrderId,
  };
  return customerDeposit;
}

function run() {
  const transferData = [{
    "id": "755",
    "entities": ["14394551"],
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "amount": 43,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14394550"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB588328"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "755",
    "entities": ["14394553"],
    "accountID": "755",
    "accountName": "122060 Test7",
    "amount": 28,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test7",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "14",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14394552"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB588333"],
    "exchangerate": 1
},{
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14439896"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 38,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14439895"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2454"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14434400"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 18,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14434399"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2453"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "758",
    "entities": ["14430895"],
    "accountID": "758",
    "accountName": "122070 Test5",
    "amount": 63,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "Test5",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "12",
    "type": "Dep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14430894"],
    "memo": ["MICGB2452"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "762",
    "entities": ["14350538"],
    "accountID": "762",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST1",
    "amount": 45,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "TEST1",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14350537"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB586991"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}, {
    "id": "760",
    "entities": ["14350538"],
    "accountID": "760",
    "accountName": "122100 TEST2",
    "amount": 49,
    "subsidiary": "2",
    "currency": "1",
    "webPaymentMethod": "TEST2",
    "webPaymentMethodID": "13",
    "type": "CustDep",
    "salesOrderId": ["14321538"],
    "memo": ["MAINGB452756"],
    "exchangerate": 1
}];

  var customerDeposit = [];
  var deposit = [];

    var res = transferData.reduce(function (agg, obj) {
      var objForId = agg.filter(function (idObj) {
        return idObj.id === obj.id;
      })[0];


      if (objForId) {
        if(obj.type === 'CustDep') {
          objForId.customerDeposit.push(createCustomerDeposit(obj));
        }
        if(obj.type === 'Dep') {
          objForId.deposit.push(createDeposit(obj));
        }
      } else {          
        agg.push({
          id: obj.id,
          accountID: obj.accountID,
          accountName: obj.accountName,
          subsidiary: obj.subsidiary,
          currency: obj.currency,
          exchangerate: obj.exchangerate,
          customerDeposit,
          deposit
        });
        customerDeposit = [];
        deposit = [];
      }

      return agg;
    }, []);


  console.log(res);

}
run();
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Hopefully the question makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Please go read [mre]. The code you have to show that is relevant to your problem, belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on some external platform.

Comment: _"I am looping through multiple JSON objects..."_ - No, you don't because [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Those are objects (hence the `json` tag is not relevant for this question)